# how to upload the excel file in akka http micro services

Tags: excel, scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

am using Akka HTTP in server side for uploading the excel sheet and saving into the local,

```
def uploadFile(fileData: Multipart.FormData) = {
println(" uploadFile ")
// path("user" / "upload" / "file") {
/* (post & entity(as[Multipart.FormData])) { fileData =>*/
complete {
  val fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString
  val temp = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")
  val filePath = temp + "/" + fileName+".xls"
  // var filePath = current.configuration.getString("upload.file.path").get + "/" + fileName
  println(fileData.getParts() + " - " + fileData.getMediaType() + " filePath " + filePath + " fileName " + fileName)
  val processingFileUpload = processFile(filePath, fileData)
  /*val poResult = Await.result(processingFileUpload, 50 seconds)
    println(" processFile " + poResult)*/
  processingFileUpload.map { fileSize =>
    HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, entity = s"File successfully uploaded. Fil size is $fileSize")
  }.recover {
    case ex: Exception => HttpResponse(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, entity = "Error in file uploading")
  }
  //  }
  // }
}
 }
```

and my processFile is

```
private def processFile(filePath: String, fileData: Multipart.FormData) =   {
  val fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(filePath)
  println(" fileOutput " + fileOutput+" fileDatas "+fileData.parts.module)
//  fileData.parts.mapAsync(1) { bodyPart =>
  fileData.parts.mapAsyncUnordered(1) { bodyPart =>
    println(" bodyPartLog " + bodyPart)
    def writeFileOnLocal(array: Array[Byte], byteString: ByteString): Array[Byte] = {
      println(" arraysdss " + array)
      val byteArray: Array[Byte] = byteString.toArray
      fileOutput.write(byteArray)
      println(" sdssasx " + byteArray)
      array ++ byteArray
    }
    bodyPart.entity.dataBytes.runFold(Array[Byte]())(writeFileOnLocal)
  }.runFold(0)(_ + _.length)
}
```

i have traied both mapAsync and mapAsyncUnordered am getting the every time Error in file uploading it's directly jumped into the exception how can write the the data into my server local through uploading the service

Comment: Are we to guess what the exception is? You'll most likely want to switch from your processFile implementation to use this: https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/FileIO$.html As your implementation currently has a number of issues, like not closing the output, reading the entire thing into memory, creating multiple copies of the data etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used another method for file uploading and it's working too

```
(post & entity(as[Multipart.FormData])) { request =>
  extractRequestContext {
    ctx => {
      implicit val materializer = ctx.materializer
      implicit val ec = ctx.executionContext
      fileUpload("fileUpload") {
        case (fileInfo, fileStream) =>

          val localPath = "c:\\test"
          val sink = FileIO.toPath(Paths.get(localPath) resolve fileInfo.fileName)
          val writeResult = fileStream.runWith(sink)
          onSuccess(writeResult) { result =>
            result.status match {
              case Success(_) => complete(s"Successfully written ${result.count} bytes")
              case Failure(e) => throw e
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```